# не могу изменить тип данных id для автоинкремента

Tags: sql, postgresql

Использую этот код для создания автоинкремента.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tables_id_applicant ;
ALTER TABLE applicant  ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT 
NEXTVAL('tables_id_applicant');
```

В итоге получаю:

> ОШИБКА: отношение "applicant" не существует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SQL-состояние: 42P01

Comment: Посмотрите [вот это](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117563/150107).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот-так

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tables_id_applicant
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE applicant  ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT 
NEXTVAL('tables_id_applicant');
```